# How to set the frame of an animation in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have made a CCAnimationHelper class that performs the following. You give it a fileName, a frameCount, and a Delay and it will give you back an animation. The thing I want to know is how to set the frame of the animation so instead of starting at frame 1, it will start at frame 10 instead. Here is my code

```
// Creates an animation from sprite frames.
+(CCAnimation*) animationWithFrame:(NSString*)frame frameCount:(int)frameCount delay:(float)delay
{
// load the ship's animation frames as textures and create a sprite frame
NSMutableArray* frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frameCount];
for (int i = 1; i < frameCount; i++)
{
    NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", frame, i];
    CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = [frameCache spriteFrameByName:file];
    [frames addObject:frame];
}

// return an animation object from all the sprite animation frames
return [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:delay]; //Is there another method I should be using here to set the frame
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in funcion that does that, but you can simply create your animation and pass it the NSArray starting at the frame you want:

```
    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animation];
    NSArray *offset = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frame3, frame4, nil];
    [animation initWithFrames:offset];
```